# Query all columns of table1 left join and count of the table2

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-server-2012, count

I couldn't get this query working :

**DOESN'T WORK**

```
select 
    Region.*, count(secteur.*) count 
from  
    Region 
left join 
    secteur on secteur.region_id = Region.id
```

The solution I found is this but is there a better solution using joins or if this doesn't affect performance, because I have a very large dataset of about 500K rows

**WORKS BUT AFRAID OF PERFORMANCE ISSUES**

```
select 
    Region.*,
    (select count(*) 
     from Secteur 
     where Secteur.Region_id = region.id) count 
from  
    Region
```

Comment: Why don't you use `COUNT(Single_Colunm)`

Comment: @PrashantPimpale Because [it makes no difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221559/count-vs-count1-sql-server).

Comment: @RuudHelderman yes, is it identical for all cases? cause had one query which takes 1 min and 13 seconds to execute which I was using `COUNT(*)` but once I changed to `COUNT(_id)` which is int value now it's taking 10 to 15 seconds to execute!

Comment: @PrashantPimpale Tested with cold cache or warm cache? Were the index statistics up to date? Did `_id` hold null values? Besides duration, did you measure I/O and CPU? Did you compare the query plans? What version and edition of SQL Server? I am willing to take your claim seriously, but without an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the claim is meaningless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd join `region` on an aggregate query of `secteur`:

```
SELECT    r.*, COALESCE(s.cnt, 0)
FROM      region r
LEFT JOIN (SELECT   region_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt
           FROM     secteur
           GROUP BY region_id) s ON s.region_id = r.id
```

Comment: in term of performance, I think it is better then my working query ??!!

Comment: @seddik But this isn't using a `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: i ve added a left join to it, and its the most convenient solution in my opinion

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest:

```
select region.*, count(secteur.region_id) as count
from region left join secteur on region.id = secteur.region_id
group by region.id, region.field2, region.field3....
```

Note that `count(table.field)` will *ignore* nulls, whereas `count(*)` will include them.

---

Alternatively, left join on a subquery and use `coalesce` to avoid nulls:

```
select region.*, coalesce(t.c, 0) as count
from region left join 
(select region_id, count(*) as c from secteur group by region_id) t on region.id = t.region_id
```

Comment: returns incorrect syntax near * (in the group by line) ??!!

Comment: Apologies, you'll need to list the fields contained in `region`, each to be grouped by.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with this query:

```
select r.*,
       (select count(*) 
        from Secteur s
        where s.Region_id = r.id
      ) as num_secteurs 
from Region r;
```

Then fix the performance problem by adding an index on `Secteur(region_id)`:

```
create index idx_secteur_region on secteur(region_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You make a two  mistakes

- First: you have try to calulate COUNT() in only one (I mean, the second) table. This doesn't will work because  theCOUNT(), like an any aggregate function, calculates only for the **whole set of rows**, not just for any part of the set (not only just for the one or an other joined table).
  In your first query, you may replace *secteur.* * only by asterisk, like a `Region.region_id, count(*) AS count`, and do not forget add Region.region_id on the `GROUP BY` step.
- Second: You has define not only aggregate function in the query, but and other fields: `select  Region.*`, but you don't define them in `GROUP BY` step. You need to add to `GROUP BY` statement all columns, which you has define in the `SELECT` step but not apply an aggregate functions to them.
- Append: not, `GROUP BY Region.*` doesn't will work, you should to define a columns in the `GROUP BY` step by their actual names.

So, correct form of this will looks like a

```
SELECT 
    Region.col1
    ,Region.col2,
    , count(*) count 
from  Region 
left join 
    secteur on secteur.region_id = Region.id
GROUP BY Region.col1, Region.col2
```

Or, if you don't want to type each name of column, use *window queries*

```
SELECT
    Region.*,
    , count( * ) OVER (PARTITION BY region_id) AS count 
from  Region 
left join 
    secteur on secteur.region_id = Region.id
```